# how can I replicate the "build and run" functionality of modern IDEs using CMake?

Tags: c, cmake, build

I have a C project that I'm creating in Linux. Building is managed with CMake. The project is split into the usual folders for source, includes and a build folder into which CMake produces an executable for me to run.

Running the binary requires setting an environment variable first, and also passing in some switches to the program's command line. It's tedious having to type out the command line every time after typing "make". Relying on the shell to recall the previous command is fine until I log out. I am aware modern IDEs provide this functionality, but I don't want my build system reliant on a specific IDE.

I want to shorten the edit-compile-run cycle by simply typing something like "make run" which should appropriately compile any source that is outdated and then run the resulting binary. Preferably without having to hard code the binary name into anything (I figure CMake knows what it is after you use add_executable(), and I want to copy this directory tree for other projects in the future).

I'm sure there is something explaining this online, but I can't figure out the correct words to put into Google to find it.

Comment: Do you want to _run_ your executable, or __test__ your executable? `Running the binary requires setting an environment variable first, and also passing in some switches to the program's command line` Then why not hardcode that into the binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having:

```
add_executable(my_exe ....)
```

To add a custom target you can do:

```
add_custom_target(run COMMAND env VARIABLE=20 $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe> ARG1 ARG2)
```

If you are testing your command, which is conceptually different then running it, then add a test:

```
add_test(NAME test1 COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe> arg1 arg)
set_property(TEST test1 PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT
      VARIABLE=something
      ANOTHER_VARIABLE=something_else
)
add_test(NAME test2 COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe> arg1 arg2)
set_property(TEST test2 PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT
      VARIABLE=something_else
      ANOTHER_VARIABLE=yet_something_else
)
etc..
```

Research [ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#manual:ctest(1)) and [cmake testing](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/testing.html).

Prefer to use `cmake --build <build_dir> --target run` instead of `make run` when working with cmake, to be generator agnostic, so that when you decide to switch to Ninja to speed up your compilation times you won't have to refactor your build process.

Comment: Fyi: If you're using `add_test`, you can set environment vars by setting [the `ENVIRONMENT` property of the test.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/ENVIRONMENT.html). If you're using visual studio on windows you could specify the environment for the visual studio debugger for the executable target using [the `VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT` target property.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT.html)

Comment: Och, wow, didn't new there's a property for that!